# high load average on KVM VM web servers

Tags: kvm, php5, memcached

I have a server with KVM libvirt and OVS. Debian 8.6.

I am currently running 2 web servers with installed nginx+php5-fpm on VM . HAProxy is used to balance requests and installed on KVM virtual machine. PHP sessions are stored on memcached on another VM. Web site is written in Yii2 framework.

Every 15 minutes or 30 minutes the load average of web servers are increasing untill 200-300. The capacity of Database is around 1GB. 
The type of site is media. A lot of contents and live tv channels.

How to solve this problem ?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add to the post if hosting services, if any CMSs, what kind of sites, and the ouput of 'uptime', 'vmstat' and 'iostat'

Comment: I have added additional info.

Comment: All the data you posted seems a somewhat healthy system. Are you able to duplicate the same data when the load problems happen?

Comment: Yes, I'm. I will catch this moment and post.

Answer (score 0):

Find the next solution: [How to stream on demand video with load balancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897525/how-to-stream-on-demand-video-with-load-balancing)

Basically is to enable a module in nginx, this may lead to improve on how the servers serve the videos and better manage their resources.

Comment: The answer that I offer is technically simple, I consider that if the answer is complex or not completely clear I would take its recommendation but this is not the case and would basically duplicate content, likewise, I will take the recommendation for future answers.